# phpIPAM isntallation on Ubuntu 22.04.03 Live Server

Tags: php, nginx, devops

I am trying to install phpIPAM on my Ubuntu live server.

[I have installed and configured it with php8.1, Nginx, MariaDB but when I try to open the ip_address/phpipam/ in browser it returs the 404 Not Found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwM1T.png)

My configuration files are:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpipam.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.10.11.76;

    root /var/www/html/phpipam;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/phpipam

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/phpipam;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 10.10.11.76;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

#    location ~ \.php$ {
#        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm8.1.sock;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock; # Adjust version if necessary
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Additional configuration for phpIPAM, if needed
}
```

/var/www/html/phpipam/config.php

```
...
/**
 * database connection details
 ******************************/
$db['host'] = 'localhost';
$db['user'] = 'phpipam';
$db['pass'] = 'my_password';
$db['name'] = 'phpipam';
$db['port'] = 3306;

...

if(!defined('BASE'))
        define('BASE', "/phpipam/");
...
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2023/12/22 13:52:33 [error] 4158#4158: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 0 in /var/www/html/phpipam/functions/classes/class.Rewrite.php on line 94PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Constant BASE already defined in /var/www/html/phpipam/config.php on line 12PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "HTTPS" in /var/www/html/phpipam/functions/classes/class.Common.php on line 828PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "HTTPS" in /var/www/html/phpipam/functions/classes/class.Common.php on line 828PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "SCRIPT_URL" in /var/www/html/phpipam/functions/classes/class.User.php on line 466PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "SCRIPT_URL" in /var/www/html/phpipam/functions/classes/class.User.php on line 466PHP message
2023/12/22 13:57:30 [warn] 4402#4402: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/22 13:57:30 [warn] 4403#4403: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 04:56:40 [warn] 7416#7416: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 04:56:40 [warn] 7417#7417: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:00:22 [warn] 7485#7485: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:00:27 [warn] 7494#7494: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:00:27 [warn] 7496#7496: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:10:03 [warn] 7705#7705: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:10:03 [warn] 7706#7706: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:13:42 [warn] 7897#7897: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 05:13:42 [warn] 7898#7898: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:19:29 [warn] 10599#10599: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:19:29 [warn] 10600#10600: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:29:12 [warn] 11078#11078: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:29:12 [warn] 11079#11079: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:29:52 [warn] 11122#11122: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:29:52 [warn] 11123#11123: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:36:15 [warn] 11180#11180: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2023/12/23 06:36:15 [warn] 11181#11181: conflicting server name "10.10.11.76" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

Can you help with its configuration please? I was expecting to enter to the Installation menu of phpIPAM.